# How do I access Blackboard API with my username and password?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, blackboard

trying to develop an application that takes data from a user's respective Blackboard account and display that information in a different way. I have been reading the blackboard API [documentation](https://help.blackboard.com/Learn/Administrator/Hosting/System_Integration/Compare_Building_Blocks_and_Rest#register-a-rest-integration-in-blackboard-learn_OTP-4) and I guess I have to go to an administrator with an App ID in order for me to obtain this kind of access. What type of information should I provide the admin being as I don't even know what an App ID is, let alone provide it. I'm just a student trying to make my life easier by consolidating information that's already available to me on blackboard. I appreciate any guidance on the development process.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you'll likely want to start with is at https://docs.blackboard.com/ - of particular note is the [REST / Getting Started](https://docs.blackboard.com/learn/REST/Getting%20Started%20With%20REST.html) section.  See also the [swagger docs](https://developer.blackboard.com/portal/displayApi) for the API, which detail the needed entitlements for each API call.